# Support for SQL Server 2016 Query Store on a SharePoint Database

Tags: database, sql-server-2016

SQL Server 2016 has a new performance tuning feature [Query Store](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store).

Query Store must be enabled at database level. All Query Store information [will be stored in the primary filegroup of the database](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-sql-server-2016-query-store-overview-and-architecture/).

Will this [change to a SharePoint database be supported by Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/841057/support-for-changes-to-the-databases-that-are-used-by-office-server-pr)? Any advice is appreciated.